# Android RelativeLayout button overlapping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a layout like this :

[image: Screenshot 1]

i wish to make btn1 vertical align to center and elements under it will push below also. But after i put android:layout_centerVertical in btn1, it was vertical align to center but the element below it is not pushing down.

Layout after i put android:layout_centerVertical="true" in btn1 :

[image: Screenshot 2]

This is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="1" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal ="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Text 1" />



            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn3"
                    android:layout_below="@id/btn2"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Some Text 2" />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn4"
                    android:layout_toRightOf ="@id/btn3"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btn3"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Some Text 3" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know that if i assign sufficient height in parent layout it will work normally but later on i will make this form as dynamically generate. Any way to make it automatically pushing down with wrap_content?

Comment: Easy way with linear layout. Just change second RelativeLyout with LinearLayout and add one property anroid:orientation="vertical"

Comment: Remove your inner `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="1" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal ="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Text 1" />



            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn3"
                    android:layout_below="@id/btn2"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Some Text 2" />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn4"
                    android:layout_toRightOf ="@id/btn3"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btn3"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Some Text 3" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

add centerInParent value to your relative layout as shown above

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">


</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Some Text 1" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Text 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/btn3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn3"
        android:text="Some Text 3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Some Text 1" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Some Text 2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn3"
                android:text="Some Text 3" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your second relative layout or set that layout height and width to *match_parent*!